# how to change color of exactly one feature (multipolygon) at a time - dynamic styling google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map using Google API. I have defined the multi-polygon layer of buildings as json file. I want to be able to click at polygon and have its color changed to another. After clicking at the second building, only second building should have changed color and the previously clicked ones should go back to their original fill. In other words, I want to be able to select only one building by click and have it displayed in different color then others.

So far I tried with dynamic styling from google map API examples [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic).
However what I got so far is only being able to click and 'unclick' buildings color. What should I do to get described results?

```
var buildings = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "buildings_layer",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name_1": "HIQ", "addr_nr": "3", "addr_stree": "Gustave-Naville-Weg", "descriptio": "Pavillon II für Architektur" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 8.508053374921182, 47.409945493110904, 524.154999999998836 ], [ 8.507733029701146, 47.409506514443301, 523.865000000005239 ], [ 8.507593213859357, 47.409553556049616, 523.740999999994528 ], [ 8.507704801729497, 47.409706338427313, 523.919999999998254 ], [ 8.507724154119826, 47.409735716985452, 523.929999999993015 ], [ 8.50791195204587, 47.40999305367589, 524.012000000002445 ], [ 8.508053374921182, 47.409945493110904, 524.154999999998836 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name_1": "HPM", "addr_nr": "3", "addr_stree": "Otto-Stern-Weg", "descriptio": "Zellbiologie \/ Biochemie" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 8.510424206560639, 47.409831344813142, 528.319000000003143 ], [ 8.510447505495517, 47.409823662930137, 528.347999999998137 ], [ 8.510480687529748, 47.409869229727256, 527.111000000004424 ], [ 8.51058712998627, 47.40983370187864, 527.600000000005821 ], [ 8.510554561494247, 47.409787679671524, 528.210999999995693 ], [ 8.510577538817596, 47.409779820844342, 528.043999999994412 ], [ 8.510591621745974, 47.409798795616886, 528.001999999993131 ], [ 8.510693918897799, 47.409764700333952, 526.967999999993481 ], [ 8.510508470488023, 47.409510179668921, 526.216000000000349 ], [ 8.510519713353803, 47.409506549373837, 526.089999999996508 ], [ 8.510483539536088, 47.409456503833148, 528.327000000004773 ], [ 8.510412296671355, 47.409479000563181, 528.046000000002095 ], [ 8.510176066911402, 47.409155053807922, 528.569000000003143 ], [ 8.510187838375566, 47.409151355679001, 528.611000000004424 ], [ 8.510160709934256, 47.409113567319714, 528.615000000005239 ], [ 8.510067967151468, 47.409143705734991, 528.57499999999709 ], [ 8.510060896837672, 47.40913409265417, 528.596999999994296 ], [ 8.509901329328159, 47.409187148927202, 528.582999999998719 ], [ 8.509935290502499, 47.409235263240461, 528.506999999997788 ], [ 8.509941580155729, 47.409233073132619, 528.509000000005472 ], [ 8.510179229753403, 47.409557973376906, 528.032000000006519 ], [ 8.510105684216887, 47.409582743734717, 528.26600000000326 ], [ 8.510142205150705, 47.409632273456758, 528.107999999992899 ], [ 8.510152339753995, 47.409628878346375, 527.959000000002561 ], [ 8.510341013793047, 47.409882067599845, 526.850999999995111 ], [ 8.51043776296215, 47.409850495390771, 527.961999999999534 ], [ 8.510424206560639, 47.409831344813142, 528.319000000003143 ] ] ] ] } },
]
}
```

My code so far:

```
var  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

map.data.addGeoJson(buildings);

map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
    if (feature.getProperty('isColorful'))
    return({
        fillColor: 'red',
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWeight:2
    });
    else
    return ({
    fillColor: 'grey',
    strokeWeight:2
    });
});

map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', !event.feature.getProperty('isColorful'));
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use simple array of `Polygon`s? Performance purpose?

Comment: I think I can, but actually this is my first time with javascript and google map API, so it is learning process so far :) This way was the first one I found and it worked. Would array of polygons be an easier solution?

Comment: I don't think so. What could be easier than four lines of code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a building, clear the `isColorful` properties of all the other buildings (or keep a reference to the one that is colored and set it back).

**clear all the buildings:**

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    feature.setProperty('isColorful',false);
  });

  event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', !event.feature.getProperty('isColorful'));
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hyroag4k/)

or

**keep a reference to the "active" building:**

```
var coloredBuilding = null;
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
  if (coloredBuilding != null) {
    coloredBuilding.setProperty('isColorful', false);
  }
  event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
  coloredBuilding = event.feature;
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hyroag4k/1/)

Comment: The first code is exactly what I was trying to do, but I was not aware of function "forEach" and I couldn't get access to all the buildings. Now it works perfectly, thanks a lot!